# How to solve a simple inequality in COQ with the same variable which is adding on both sides of the inequality

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

As you can see I am pretty close to build a proof in COQ, however I am stuck in such inequation. Which is pretty clear, since `l2 = hd2 :: tl2`. I just want to get rid of the `length l1` from both sides of the inequation.

How can I do that? I think that there is a simple solution for this... Maybe it is just a theorem which is already in COQ?

```
p : list ℕ * list ℕ 
l1, l2 : list ℕ 
hd1 : ℕ 
tl1 : list ℕ 
teq0 : l1 = hd1 :: tl1 
hd2 : ℕ 
tl2 : list ℕ 
teq1 : l2 = hd2 :: tl2 
teq : p = (l1, l2) 
teq2 : (hd1 <=? hd2) = false
-----------------------------------------------
length l1 + length tl2 < length l1 + length l2
```

Comment: Use `Search (?X + _ < ?X + _).` and similar to look for existing lemmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may first replace `l2`with `hd2::tl2` (with `subst` or `rewrite H`), then `cbn`. Then look for arithmetic lemmas (as shown by `htnw`) or use `auto with arith`.